# Easily add element to varargs list

Tags: java

I have these signatures:

```
  public static <T, E> AsyncTask<List<T>, E> Parallel(AsyncTask<T,E> t, AsyncTask<T, E>... tasks) {
    return cb -> NeoParallel.Parallel(List.of(tasks), cb);
  }

  public static <T, E> AsyncTask<List<T>, E> Series(AsyncTask<T,E> t, AsyncTask<T, E>... tasks) {
    return cb -> NeoSeries.Series(List.of(tasks), cb);
  }
```

how can I easily add `t` to the `List.of(tasks)`?

This won't work because it creates an immutable list:

```
var listOfTasks = Arrays.asList(tasks);
listOfTasks.add(0, t);
```

is there a way to easily create a list that I can add to, or do it in one line?

Since this call is likely unperformant:

```
   listOfTasks.add(0, t);
```

I am looking for an alternative

Comment: can you modify those signatures to have only the varargs?

Comment: You can use [Collections.unmodifiableList(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) to get an unmodifiable version of a list.

Comment: There is no concise way within Java's API to do what you want that I know of (you can of course always transform the modifiable list to an unmodifiable list through [`Collections.toUnmodifiableList(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List))). The question that comes to my mind is: why is the parameter `t` separated in the method's signature?

Comment: By the way, `Arrays.asList` produces a fixed-size list, not supporting `add`.

Comment: @Turing85 might be for performance reasons.

Comment: @Turing85 Or to force at least one argument.

Comment: @LppEdd or maybe because the answer was 42 :) Would like to hear an answer from OP ;)

Comment: @Turing85 hahaha nice movie (and good book) ;)

Comment: @njzk2 it's not only varargs because I need the user to pass at least one argument, o/w I want the compiler to complain

Answer (score 1):

There is no concise way to create the list. Probably your best option is to create a new list, add both the array elements and the new element to the list and return a unmodifiable list using `Collections.unmodifiableList`.

```
    List<T> newList = new ArrayList<>(tasks.length + 1);
    newList.addAll(Arrays.asList(tasks));
    newList.add(t);
    List<T> unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(newList);
```

Comment: minor detail nitpick but I don't think the `args.length + 1` is necessary here, prob can just omit it?

Comment: @AlexanderMills it is not needed, for sure (because all lists are dynamic data structures), but is provieds a (very minor) performance increase :)

Comment: if I want to put t in the first position  aka, `newList.add(0,t)`, not sure how to make that performant. I assume it has to go through the whole list and shift everything one index over..so damn

Comment: ultimately my question is how to make the performant (avoiding this call `newList.add(0,t)`) since that's pretty unperformant call.

Comment: You can just switch the order. Create the new list, call the method `add(t)` and then call the method `addAll()`.

Answer (score 1):

While a short & performant (well maybe this isn't bad at all!) solution isn't possible with the current Java `API`, I'll showcase a one-liner with the help of `Stream`(s).

```
return cb -> NeoSeries.Series(concat(of(t), of(tasks)).collect(toList()), cb);
```

This line

```
concat(of(t), of(tasks)).collect(toList())
```

expanded becomes

```
Stream.concat(Stream.of(t), Stream.of(tasks))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is lazily computed, and will avoid temporary state.

---

What the other answer fail to mention is null-handling. What if the varargs array is null? `Arrays.asList` would throw an `Exception`. The same for `Stream.of`

For that you can write a masking method such as

```
private static <T, E> AsyncTask<T, E>[] maskNull(final AsyncTask<T, E>[] tasks) {
    return tasks != null ? tasks : (AsyncTask<T, E>[]) new AsyncTask[0];
}
```

And use it like

```
of(maskNull(tasks))
```

Comment: thanks I updated the OP to make it a little bit better, but this might work

Comment: @AlexanderMills I updated the answer to reflect the desired result

Comment: @AlexanderMills I also added varargs null handling.

Comment: since Java 16 we can use `.toList()` on `Stream` directly instead of `.collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the show, but you can use [Guava Lists](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#asList(E,%20E%5B%5D)).

```
var listOfTasks = com.google.common.collect.Lists.asList(t, tasks);
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I got:

before:

```
var tasks = Arrays.asList(args);
tasks.add(0,t);  // throws exception
```

after:

```
var newList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(args));
newList.add(0,t);
```

the problem with the first one is it creates an immutable list that will throw an exception if you try to add to it after it's first created.

Comment: Have you considered the one-liner I posted above?

Comment: Honestly not considering it since it's overcomplicated, I might copy/paste that code and never understand it again :/ I am however not that satisfied with my answer here either.  The call `newList.add(0,t);` is not performant, I am looking for one liner that can I add everything to array at once.

Comment: You need a trade-off. Honestly, with the added null-check, both solutions would be "over-complicated". Just document your code well and you'll be fine. I use Stream(s) daily like that and it is a matter of being used to it. As I stated in the answer, via Stream you avoid temporary state, which is awesome imho

Comment: You also don't need to explicity insert at an index, shifting the array. The two Streams are merged internally as  a single sequence.